# sql/php return rows that are older than 2 weeks

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So after 3 hours of sleeping and going through every single article/question there is for this but I simply couldn't get it to work. My date column is in Y-m-d format, what I'm trying to get is all the rows that are past 2 weeks of the date available which is stated in the table.

This is the closest I've gotten it, but it doesn't return all of the rows still.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',time()+(14*86400));
SELECT * FROM table_claims WHERE date_available > '$date'
```

An solution to this would make my day so much easier, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you meant to state `date_available > '$date'` instead of `date_available < '$date'`? You are looking for rows that are OLDER, right?

Comment: Yup, I guess I need to good night sleep, thanks @DaanMeijer

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',time()-(14*86400));
```

will generate a $date for two weeks ago.

Also you can use a MYSQL function in the SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM table_claims WHERE date_available < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -2 WEEK)
```

Comment: change `>` to the `<` and it will be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> hey @Ale if you want to get past time(weeks, minutes, seconds) like in
>   your case you want weeks, so you can use the format => strtotime("- 2 weeks/- 1
>   minutes") etc it will give you that timestamp

Now In your case try below one:

```
<?php
     $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("- 2 weeks"));
     SELECT * FROM table_claims WHERE date_available < '$date'
?>
```

It will give all the date_available smaller than two week or you can change your logic according to you (y)

Comment: OP made the same mistake on the question example. Older than two weeks means less than two weeks not greater than two weeks.